# Сравнение слов в Python аналогично тому, как это делается в MySQL при использовании utf8_general_ci

Tags: python, mysql

У меня есть база MySQL с сопоставлением (collation) `utf8_general_ci` (если точнее, MariaDB и `utf8mb4_general_ci`, но, думаю, не суть), из-за чего при сравнениях некоторые неодинаковые строки считаются равными: например, буквы `е` и `ё` считаются одинаковыми. Однако мне необходимо делать одинаковые сравнения строк и в MySQL, и в Python: строки, считающиеся равными в MySQL, оказываются неравными в Python, из-за чего в моей программе иногда случаются сбои.

```
>>> "еж" == "ёж"
False

MariaDB [(none)]> select 'еж' = 'ёж' as c;
+---+
| c |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
```

Каким образом я могу сравнивать или преобразовывать строки в Python так, чтобы поведение было аналогично `utf8_general_ci` в MySQL? (Сортировка не интересует — только равно/не равно.)

Иначе говоря, требуется такое поведение:

```
>>> "еж" == "ёж"
True
```

Разумеется, меня интересует не только е/ё, но и всё остальное поведение `utf8_general_ci`:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select 'u' = 'ṻ' as c;
+---+
| c |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

MariaDB [(none)]> select 'O' = 'ø' as c;
+---+
| c |
+---+
| 0 |
+---+
```

Comment: Мне кажется имеет смысл отказаться от collation и сравнивать в mysql бинарные строки. А для случаев когда, вам вдруг нужен utf8_general_ci использовать его явно. Если нужны какие-то правила для е/ё (или любые другие), то явно прописать это в программе.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202726/writing-utf-8-string-to-mysql-with-python ?

Comment: @ʞɔᴉNɹǝꓥ чёт не понял при чём тут это

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19830643/4928642

Comment: Впрочем, [не работает](https://ideone.com/STy4Xy). А вообще, `е` и `ё` - это разные буквы. Javascricpt (а именно `"ё".localeCompare("е")`) не считает их равными. Может стоит mysql потыкать, чтобы он передумал?

Comment: Да, Е и Ё - разные буквы. А "ЕЖ" и "ЁЖ" - разные слова. Может, в Вашем случае, будет правильнее при работе с БД все Ё заменить на Е, раз вы не уважаете эту букву?

Comment: @Qwertiy зато `"ё".localeCompare("е", undefined, {sensitivity: "base"})` уже считает равными :)

Answer (score 6):

Если мы посмотрим на [таблицы сравнения из MySQL](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_unicode_ci.european.html), то мы увидим что `е` и `ё` в них считаются за одну букву. Там же можно найти другие таблицы сравнения, конкретно нас интересуют [таблицы сравнения для кириллицы](http://collation-charts.org/icu442/icu442-ru.html) из ICU. Это то, что нужно, потому что, по счастью, есть модуль для связи с API ICU.

Модуль требует сами библиотеки ICU, потом проще будет установить всё так:

```
sudo apt install python3-icu
```

Используем:

```
>>> from icu import Collator, Locale
>>> col = Collator.createInstance(Locale('ru'))
>>> col.equals(u'ё', u'е')
False
```

Это не то, что нам нужно. Такая ситуация существует потому что по умолчанию используются более строгие правила сравнения ([сила сравнения](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1Collator.html#a82bc20541fe4503fb78644a1968e15a2) в терминах ICU). Конкретно нам нужно установить [силу сравнения](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/coll_8h_source.html#l00197) в значение `PRIMARY`, чтобы при сравнении игнорировались вторичные отличия такие как точки над буквой. Тогда сравнение работает так, как мы хотим:

```
>>> col.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY)
>>> col.equals(u'ё', u'е')
True
>>> col.equals(u'я', u'е')
False
```

При этом сравнения других букв работают как прежде.

Конечно, если требуется сравнение букв *за пределами* русской локали, то нужно выбирать другую локаль. Можно, например, делать сравнение перебором по нескольким локалям ([или по всем](http://collation-charts.org/icu442/)), и если хотя бы в одной при сравнении будет `True`, останавливать перебор.

Конечно, этот подход не гарантирует полного 100% соответствия `utf8_general_ci`, лишь только практическое соответствие результатов 
сравнения для большинства случаев. Если нужно чтобы всё было *точно* как в `utf8_general_ci`, то остаётся только искать те таблицы, которые использует это сравнение, специфичное для MySQL, и изобретать что-то своё на их основе, при этом нужно не забыть [про подводные камни нормализации](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

---

Есть также вариант не делать сравнения оффлайн, а делать их онлайн, подключившись к MySQL и делая запросы по каждому сравнению. Из вашего же примера:

```
select 'O' = 'ø' as c;
```

Никаких действий с таблицами этот запрос не подразумевает, потому выполняться такие запросы будут настолько быстро, насколько возможно. Это будет самый простой и, одновременно, самый точный способ выполнить задачу, если принципиально чтобы была 100% эквивалентность сравнений. Если сервер MySQL, на котором живёт БД, находится физически на другом сервере, то нет  никакой проблемы запустить локальную копию сервера MySQL без баз данных и без ничего, и делать сравнения используя эту локальную копию демона MySQL. Или демона MariaDB, суть та же самая.

Comment: К сожалению, пробное сравнение случайных строк сразу выдало кучу несоответствий. Например, строки `O` и `ø` этот код считает одинаковыми, в то время как mysql — разными

Comment: А вот первая ссылка на таблицу выглядит полезной — наверно, с её помощью можно навелосипедить нужное поведение)

Comment: @andreymal `O` и `ø` не в русской локали. Выберете соответствующую локаль для сравнения и все будет.

Comment: И какую локаль мне нужно выбрать для полного соответствия utf8_general_ci?)

Comment: @andreymal видимо только и остаётся использовать все локали по очереди

Answer (score -1):

```
if "ë" in string:
    string.replace('ë','e')
```

Comment: Костыль, не отвечающий на вопрос.